# Display records linked with two IDs

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table

```
ID NAME
--------
1  AAA
2  BBB
2  AAA
2  CCC
1  DDD
2  DDD
```

I have to display records which are linked with both ID 1 and 2

```
NAME
----
AAA
DDD
```

I am using below query -

```
Select Name from table1 where ID IN (1,2);
```

But it is displaying me -

```
NAME
-----
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

How do I change my query to solve this problem?

Comment: +1 despite being a quite easy problem to solve, this question is well formed and showed an adequate effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME
FROM tabel1 t1
join table1 t2
on t1.id = 1 and t2.id = 2 and t1.name = t2.name
```

or if there can be many matches

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME
FROM tabel1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t2 WHERE t1.name = t2.name and t2.id = 2)
and t1.id = 1
```

or

```
SELECT NAME FROM tabel1 WHERE id = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT NAME FROM tabel1 WHERE id = 2
```

Comment: Wow, thanks that was really helpful. So many ways, never even thought about that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to group by the name, then count the distinct IDs that you wish to filter by.

```
select name
from table
where id in (1,2)
group by name
having count (distinct ID) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Name 
from table1 
where ID IN (1,2)
and Name in  ( select Name               
                 from table1 
                where ID IN (1,2)
               group by Name
               having count(id) =2 
             ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Name from TableName 
where id in (1,2)
 group by Name having Count(Distinct Id)>1
```

Comment: while this query may solve the problem for this particular dataset, I'm afraid it might not work with a complex one.

Comment: @STTLCU sorry i didnt get u?

Comment: Sorry, my bad I misunderstood your query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name 
from table t
where id = 1 and exists 
(select 1 from table where name = t.name and id = 2)
```